# Reading product of same ByteArrays

Tags: performance-tuning, simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation, binary

I am handling a huge set of data and I am trying to optimize my code. I have very large expressions to expand and simplify and I've seen that converting the expressions to ByteArrays improves a lot the time spent by Mathematica to expand and simplify.

However, I have the following problem. I want to convert the following expressions

```
expr = BinarySerialize[2] BinarySerialize[2]
expr2 = BinarySerialize[3] BinarySerialize[2]
```

To do that, I run the following commands

```
BinaryDeserialize /@ expr
BinaryDeserialize /@ expr2
```

In the first case, I get the error `BinaryDeserialize: 2 is not a valid ByteArray`, while the second case works perfectly. This is because `expr` automatically takes the form of `Power[a_,b_]`. How can I overcome this difficulty in a smart way?

Comment: @MarcoB sorry, I messed up the command when I wrote the post. I meant `BinarySerialize` instead of `ByteArray`. I edited the post, sorry again!

Comment: Would `expr /. ba_ByteArray :> BinaryDeserialize[ba]` do what you need?

Comment: I do not think that  ByteArray  (the return value of BinarySerialize) are meant for calculations, but for storing data. You can see what is going on by using  Trace. In the first example "expr" is the square of an ByteArray. Obviously "BinaryDeserialize" assumes wrongly that the exponent is also a ByteArray.

Comment: @DanielHuber I use `BinarySerialize` to speed up a Parallel computation which involves a huge amount of data.

Comment: @MarcoB thank you very much!